# NuGet packages need to be restored before building. NuGet MSBuild targets are missing and are needed for building

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, nuget-package-restore

I am using Visual Studio Version 8.10.8 (latest) in macOS Big Sur. I have cloned a repository of Asp .Net project. When I try to run the project I get

> NuGet packages need to be restored before building. NuGet MSBuild
> targets are missing and are needed for building. The NuGet MSBuild
> targets are generated when the NuGet packages are restore

this error.

Screenshot:
[csproj of main project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yag8.jpg)
[Image of error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxdpu.png)

Comment: Have you tried "dotnet restore" at the command line (in the appropriate path)? Then "dotnet build"

Answer (score 7):

On your visual studio sidebar, click on the drop down dependencies folder. You will then find the NuGet folder, right click on it then select restore. It should work afterwards.

Comment: Getting this in a working solution for VS2022/Win if I try to open the it in VS2022-preview/Mac. The solution to right-click **Dependencies** and choose **Restore** worked like a charm. The only reference the "broken" project had was **Microsoft.NETCore.App** - 6.0.5, exactly the .NET version this release of VS2022 brings, so it really looks like an unnecessary step from VS2022.

Answer (score 4):

Somehow using a VPN solved my Issue.

Answer (score 0):

It may happens because you had wrong sdk definition. Everything was fine when update *global.json* file