# Visual Studio 2022 Mac Error: NuGet packages need to be restored before building. NuGet MSBuild targets are missing and are needed for building

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-mac, visual-studio-mac-2022

I have a .Net 6 project, I am getting the below error.

> Error: NuGet packages need to be restored before building. NuGet
> MSBuild targets are missing and are needed for building. The NuGet
> MSBuild targets are generated when the NuGet packages are restored.

**csproj file:**

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <DockerfileContext>..\..</DockerfileContext>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Visual studio version:** 17.4.2

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69146296/6527049) question also (restoring the packages), But it didn't help.

But I am able to build from the terminal using `dotnet build` successfully.

Also, I have other projects targeting .net 6 and I can build successfully using visual studio.

Comment: Can this be some strange connectivity issues with VS2022? Had also some issues with the 2022 version and had to use the 2019 version instead. Can you try to restore the packages via CLI? And also try to clean the obj and bin folder if they are present

Comment: I have tried cleaning the solution, but it didn't work.  @Aaron

Comment: Does the restore work in VS Mac? That error happens when VS Mac cannot find the project's obj/project.assets.json file. Does this project use some custom NuGet restore or put this file somewhere else?

Comment: @MattWard restore is happening correctly

Comment: Does the obj/project.assets.json file exists for the project that is failing even though restore is succeeding?

Comment: @MattWard it’s present